# Laravel Queues: jobs sometimes executed twice or triple

Tags: laravel, queue

I'm running Laravel 7 on XAMPP, Windows 10.
I open about 10 terminals with this command:

```
php artisan queue:work --timeout=0 --tries=1
```

Jobs are being executed once and sometimes twice, and I caught this job being executed by 3 workers:
[image: Screenshot]

I can't figure out why, and I can't reproduce the error on purpose.
I created a table to store events, and later I caught this triple execution :
[image: Events]

So, I'm sure that the job is dispatched only once.

Comment: Jobs will always be dispatched once only, unless you are using a load balancer. There could be some logical bug while saving these events.

Comment: Can we see code on how you are saving these events on while a job is being executed

Comment: @DeepeshThapa I created a database table, added a line of code that inserts rows to the table, at the beginning of dispatching code, after dispatching, at the beginning of the job, and at the end of the job

Comment: can we see your code? update your answer with code you wrote on jobs